# gcc: Double NULL sentinel attribute?

Tags: gcc, attributes, sentinel

I have a variadic function that requires a double-NULL terminator.

*Contrived, Simplified Example*

```
void makeLine(char *name, ...) {
    ... accepts (x,y) coordinates until (0,0) is found,
    ... assume that any coordinate except (0,0) is legal
            [i.e. (0,1) or (1,0) should not trigger a stop condition]
}
```

And I'd like to annotate it with [*__attribute ((sentinel))__* from gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). But it seems that with the sentinel attribute, only one of the arguments can be required NULL as opposed to the desired *sentinel(0,1)* [last two required to be NULL].

Is there a way to ask gcc to enforce a double-NULL, or...

Given that the NULL can only be enforced for one of the two parameters, would you decorate this function with *sentinel(0)* or *sentinel(1)* and why? Which of the two positions would be more likely to catch bugs?

Comment: Please clarify how contrived and simplified your example is!  `__attribute__((sentinel))` isn't appropriate at all for checking for an integer 0 - which is not necessarily the same thing as a null pointer in a context where the compiler does not know the type (as is the case with a variadic function).  As the documentation you linked to says: "This function attribute ensures that a parameter in a function call is an explicit `NULL`.  [...]  *A valid `NULL` in this context is defined as zero with any pointer type.*  [...]".

Comment: Too contrived apparently, they should be pointers, not integers. The intent was to clarify that NULL would not be interpreted as a legal coordinate (as a pointer of value 0 and integer of value 0 to a naiive variadic function would be indistinguishable). I was trying to distill the question down - didn't mean to introduce confusion in the process.

Comment: Read again assumption `any legal x or y cannot be 0` and think do you really need TWO nulls ?

Comment: Flaw of the contrived example, edited to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the only way to achieve compilation error in case of any of TWO sentinels is missing - is to use C99 [variadic macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wformat"

void checkSentinel0(char * name, ...) __attribute__ ((sentinel(0)));
void checkSentinel1(char * name, ...) __attribute__ ((sentinel(1)));

void checkSentinel0(char * name, ...) {
    (void)name;
}
void checkSentinel1(char * name, ...) {
    (void)name;
}

#define MY_VARIADIC(name, ...) do {checkSentinel0(name, __VA_ARGS__);\
                                   checkSentinel1(name, __VA_ARGS__);\
                                       myVariadic(name, __VA_ARGS__);}\
                               while(0);

void myVariadic(char * name, ...) {
    // your code messing with coordinates and etc.
    (void)name;
}

int main () {

 MY_VARIADIC("test", 1,2,3,4, NULL, NULL); // Ok

 MY_VARIADIC("test", 1,2,3,4, 14,     15); // not compilable
 MY_VARIADIC("test", 1,2,3,4, NULL,   15); // not compilable
 MY_VARIADIC("test", 1,2,3,4, 15,   NULL); // not compilable

 return 0;
}
```

So if user is only exposed to your macro `MY_VARIADIC` then he/she will get error in case forgetting to terminate argument list with two null's.